# Blowing Away All Libvirt Items?

Tags: libvirt

I recently started playing with Libvirt, and I have come to the discovery that I like using virsh more so than I do the GUI client, as it is easier to interact with as far as a screenreader is concerned. With that in mind, how can I blow away all the things I did in the GUI? Or better yet, get Libvirt back to its freshly installed state as though I had done nothing at all? I am running on an Arch Linux system, if that makes a difference in the instructions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no particularly easy or right way to do this.

virsh will show you anything you created via the GUI so in that sense you dn't need to blow everything away. You can use `virsh undefine` to delete any VMs you create though. There are flags to this command to make it delete storage too if desired.

If you want a really clean setup, the uninstall all libvirt distro pacakges, and then purge the `/etc/libvirt`, `/var/run/libvirt`, `/var/cache/libvirt` and `/var/lib/libvirt` directories.

Comment: uninstalling, purging, then reinstalling has worked out nicely. Thank you.